# Drupal, Views: multiselection and search needed

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

**general question:**
is possible to enable multiselection in Drupal Views ?

**specific question**:
I've created an alternative View to display more information about my website authenticated users. However now I'm missing this control:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/unblock.png

and a search field, where I can type any user information to retrieve him. (I remember I was able to enable Search control on node views but I cannot find in a user view.

can I have these 2 functionalities in Views ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views bulk operations and exposed filters can solve this problem for you. Normally you use it to create a customized node view, but the same principal can be used for users.

Comment: hi, my issue is that there is not Used Search in exposed filters. The search field is only existing for nodes.